# How to populate Header Cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

I have a UITableView Header that I need to populate. I am using `ViewForHeaderInSection`  The datasource array is created by cells of Footer Section after I select them (I choose favorite cells that I want to "pin to top".

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderViewCell") as? HeaderTableViewCell
    headerCell?.name.text = favoritecells //how can I select the source?
    return headerCell
}
```

How can I fill this function?

Answer (score 0):

You have array of section titles

```
let headerTitle = sectionTitles[section]
```

OR you may add sectionTitles variable in favouriteCell

```
headerCell?.name.text = favoritecells.sectionTitles[section]
```

Comment: favoritecells is an array, do you mind helping me in the chat?

Comment: thanks a lot, how can we do it? I will wait in the chat until you are active?

Comment: oh ok, I still dont know how to put the sectionTitles variable. Do you know about any example of this kind of feature? or project I can look as a guide?

Comment: share a chat so I can help you

Comment: I cant find where I can use the chat, I think I have not enough reputation to use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162503/discussion-between-sh-khan-and-maruta).